# change read/write user permissions in windows server 2012 from java code

Tags: java, account-security, windows-server

I would like to code the following :

In a windows server 2012-R2 administrator account, I have a my java application which launches an external application to run in a restricted user account. My java application also changes the user account windows permissions (read/write) as required.

1- Is it possible to launch an external application from a java processBuilder in one account and run the application in a different windows account?

2- Is it possible to change a windows server 2012-R2 users permission from java? only through a PS script?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Launch an External Application**

You can use `ProcessBuilder` to start a `Process` where `PSExec` is used to execute processes as a different user.

`psexec.exe -u username -p password foo.exe`

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/pxexec.aspx

**Change a Windows Server 2012 R2 User's Permission**

For executable file, you can use `Icacls`.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753525(v=ws.11).aspx

For PowerShell script, you can use `Get-NTFSAccess`, `Add-NTFSAccess` and `Remove-NTFSAccess`.

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/11/22/weekend-scripter-use-powershell-to-get-add-and-remove-ntfs-permissions/

Comment: you're a champ!